# Notify my application on Alarm trigger event

Tags: android

I need to get a receiver in my application to listen fr any triggered alarms on the phone. so user can set an alarm on the phones calendar or alarm clock. and if it it gets triggered i want my app to be notified.

I don't want the alarm to be set from inside my application.

Comment: So you need notification in your status bar?

Comment: no, just to get the event of alarm alert to my app in a reviever